# Run second execute command if first execute command is successful

Tags: python, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to make my code not loop the whole entire thing over and over, I am trying to make it stop and loop only the first execute if nothing happens there. The function at execute command 1 is it reads data from a card and stores it into the db.
This is the current if statement I am trying to use with the code:

EDIT
currently the comman2 is executed first followed by c1 and the program keeps looping even if there is no input
I am trying to make the first execute(command2) to stay at comman2 if there is no input and only move to c1 (second execute) when there is input

```
import serial
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
ser = serial.Serial('COM4',9600)

print("Serial input ready..")
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="rfid",
  passwd="rfidpasswd",
  database="rfid"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()    
try:
  while True:
    line = ser.readline().strip()
    l= line
    data = line.decode('ascii').split(':')
    rid = data[0]
    tag = data[1]
    t = datetime.now() -timedelta(minutes = 190 )

    command2 = "INSERT INTO tag_logs (reader_id, tag_no) VALUES ('" +rid+ "','" +tag+ "')"
    mycursor.execute(command2)
    mydb.commit() 

    c1 = "Select * From tag_logs where reader_id = 'Reader_001' and timestamp > '" + str(t) +"' and tag_no = '"+tag+"'"

    print(c1)

    n=mycursor.execute(c1)


    result1 = mycursor.fetchall()
    print((n))
    print (len(result1))
    x= (len(result1))

    mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    if x > 0:   
       ser.write(b'H')
       print('done')


    else:

      ser.write(b'L')
      print('deny')

    if l == 1:
      n=mycursor.execute(c1)

    else:
      mycursor.execute(command2)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
  pass
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question a bit? When exactly should the loop be conducted and when not?

Comment: This looks to be prone for **race conditions**, imagine a other insert or more inserts also happens with the same `tag_no` the select query also might pick up those records because of the `timestamp >` filter.

Comment: Also the code looks the be prone for SQL injections.

Comment: You need a `break` statement to stop the loop.

Comment: You have `print((n))` before you do `n  = mycursor.execute(c1)`.

Comment: `if l == 1:` will never be true, because `l` is a string, not a number.

Comment: I tried adding a break after the command2 execute but it it just stops everything

Comment: What do you mean by "no input"? From the serial port? Doesn't `ser.readline()` just wait for input before it returns?

Comment: the print(n) prints n=mycursor.execute(c1)

Comment: by no input I just mean it has nothing to read

Comment: i have define l as a variable